# An encrypted conversation

Tags: cipher

My friend and I decided to see who could confuse each other the most in terms of using a cipher. The online conversation went something like this:

```
Friend: jr;;p vpmt@. jpe str upi
Me: [answers logically]
Me: Aikcw rgua~
Friend: [answers logically]
Friend: Is that the best you got?
Me: Of course not.
Me: yfek ek l cey fgluji cry e yurky ey oeaa gw xebiat
Friend: Hmmm...
```

Some say he's still "Hmmm"ing to this day.

Decode each of the three statements:

1. `jr;;p vpmt@. jpe str upi`
2. `Aikcw rgua~`
3. `yfek ek l cey fgluji cry e yurky ey oeaa gw xebiat`

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this question assumes American readers. I tried to make sense of it from here in the UK but some characters just weren't working as you intended.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Regrettably, that's not preventable as far as preserving the original question goes. Had I told the puzzler that they would need a QWERTY keyboard, it makes the already easy problem quite trivial indeed. I could have perhaps created a clue that would give this notion, but I think that would have unnecessarily obscured a nice, easy, albeit American, puzzle. If you have any suggestions on how to make it more "universal" while keeping the core of the puzzle in tact, I'm all ears.

Comment: most of it is fine. `~` causes the major issue. (`@` is a bit iffy)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. jr;;p vpmt@. jpe str upi

   > **hello conr!, how are you**
   >  (transposed on the keyboard one key to the left)
2. Aikcw rgua~

   > **Solve this!**
   >  (transposed on the keyboard one key to the right)
3. yfek ek l cey fgluji cry e yurky ey oeaa gw xebiat

   > **this is a bit hgarde but i trust it will go nicely**
   >  (mirrored on the keyboard, counting in the same number of keys from the opposite side of the keyboard, using only letter keys)
   >  I'm assuming the "fgluji" => "hgarde" is an error and is supposed to be "flujiu" => "harder"(?)

Comment: Gah, ninja'd. You might want to add explanations though.

Comment: @Deusovi - yeah, was being a bit dodgy and answering then editing the explanations, as I didn't think it would live for long...

Comment: I think the first sentence should read 'conr!'.

Comment: I threw in a few typos for good measure so that standard word-frequency analysis might be misleading

Comment: @Ankoganit - thanks, that one was just a fat finger error

Comment: hgarde is the new covfefe

Answer (score 5):

jr;;p vpmt@. jpe str upi

> Hello conr!, how are you

Aikcw rgua~

> Solve this!

yfek ek l cey fgluji cry e yurky ey oeaa gw xebiat

> this is a bit hgarde but i trust it will go nicely